# Is there a way that I can merge the following update queries into one?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, optimization, update

Is it possible to merge the following update queries into a single query?

```
        UPDATE 
        tag.ItemTagValue
        SET [Value] = @firstNode
        WHERE FkTagID = 6 and TagIndex = 1

        UPDATE tag.ItemTagValue
        SET [Value] = 'Unknown'
        WHERE FkTagID = 7 and TagIndex = 1

        UPDATE tag.ItemTagValue
        SET [Value] = 'Unknown'
        WHERE FkTagID = 8 and TagIndex = 1
```

Comment: Merging the last two should be easy.  What is the objective?  Merging may not be more efficient nor more readable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, using a [searched `CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Note that your third `UPDATE` is the same as the second in your example, btw.

```
UPDATE
    tag.ItemTagValue
SET
    [Value] = 
        CASE
            WHEN FkTagID = 6 THEN @firstNode
            WHEN FkTagID = 7 THEN 'Unknown'
            -- Whatever the third situation was supposed to be...
            ELSE [Value]
        END
WHERE
    TagIndex = 1
;
```

Comment: Sorry  I edited the question. Third update was supposed to be for 8. Not 7.

Comment: I'm guessing you can work out the third line then. The `IN` expression in the `WHERE` clause in [Julien Vavasseur's answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120042/9406) should improve performance, if there's a lot of data to consider.

Comment: No, this is not equivalent to the 3 updates in the question. This will update **all rows with TagIndex = 1** (possibly millions) while the 3 updates will update only rows with `(TagIndex = 1 AND FkTagID IN (6, 7, 8))`. The (possibly) many rows with `TagIndex = 1` and `FkTagID` different than 6, 7 and 8 will of course experience a dummy update `Value=Value`. The result thoug of the update may be different to the original 3 updates due to any `update` triggers. And the performance may be far more worse for a large table, even if the result is the same.

Comment: @ypercube fair points. Your own answer would of course be welcome...

Answer (score 4):

You can use this query:

```
UPDATE tag.ItemTagValue
SET [Value] = case 
    when FkTagID = 6 then @firstNode 
    when FkTagID = 7 then 'Unknown'
    when FkTagID = 8 then 'Unknown'
end
WHERE FkTagID in (6, 7, 8) and TagIndex = 1;
```

`FkTagID in (6, 7, 8)` may be removed if they are the only possibilities but it may help if you have an index on `FkTagID` or other values for `FkTagID` that don't need update.

A more generic query looks like this:

```
UPDATE tag.ItemTagValue
SET [Value] = case 
    when FkTagID = 6 then @firstNode 
    when FkTagID = 7 then 'Unknown'
    when FkTagID = ... then ...
    else ... end
WHERE FkTagID in (6, 7, ...) and TagIndex = 1;
```

Comment: +1. And sorry for being pedantic but there is still (small but still) a possibility that this one update may produce a different state in the database than the original 3 updates (in case of any `UPDATE` triggers which will be fired once for this but 3 times for the original.)

Comment: Good comment and useful warning. Although we don't have this level of details in this case.